# Map library supporting linestring curve rendering to produce flow map

Tags: web-mapping, flow, flow-map

Is there some function/plugin for any javascript map library (OL, leaflet, ArcGIS API for JS) to render WFS or Geojson LineStrings not as simple line but as curves?

I want to make mobility flow maps of region sequences (centroid of areas) and drawing everything just as LineStrings is just messy and confusing.

I would like to be able to create not just overlapping LineStrings, but curves and possibly have styling options like adding an arrow representing a direction of flow (middle, per interval, etc.).

Another possibility is to draw "subway" like map/diagram where LineStrings are shifted next to each other.

Also, there could be some function to automatically sum the "edge" values between same nodes and represent that part only once with weighted LineString.

Comment: do you know d3js by Mike Bostock? You'll find very exiting examples on his d3js-Gallery: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery
If you can't find it there...

Comment: Yes I know, I couldn't find anything, but I wasn't browsing everything. I found only this plugin which can be probably used - http://elfalem.github.io/Leaflet.curve/

Comment: As far as i know these kind of maps are called "tube maps" in english and a quick search for "tube maps javascript" gave me some hints, eg. http://kalyani.com/2010/10/subway-map-visualization-jquery-plugin/ or (with d3) http://bl.ocks.org/nicola/69730fc4180246b0d56d - unluckily without parallel lines at station and no curves